# jQuery ketchup plugin : accept letters only?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the validate ketchup plugin from http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/

What i'm trying to find is a way to make some of my form fields accept letters only, no numbers, etc...

Any sugestion? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First off, having looked at the docs and the structure of the plugin, I'm not a huge fan, and I'd recommend you look at some other jQuery validation solutions (such as [this](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) - if nothing else you'll probably benefit from the larger community to respond to your issues).

That said, the following seems to work for me:

```
$.ketchup.validation('justLetters', 'Contains more than letters!', function(form, el, value) { 
    return (value.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/) == null)
});
```

Try out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wCSK/1/) to see it in action. All we're doing is checking the value, and trying to match any characters which aren't between A and Z (lower and uppercase allowed). To allow for other characters, just add them before the end of the `]`, so if you want to allow spaces e.g. you could use `[^a-zA-Z ]`. This syntax is using regular expressions if you're interested.

To validate your input using the 'justLetters' method, simply use:

```
<input type="text" data-validate="validate(justLetters)" />
```